# string pattern not matching correctly

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML piece of code

```
<page>U1/68/5, U1/73/2, V1/65B/43, V5/4E/8E</page>
```

and i'm trying the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="page"> 
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([a-zA-Z][0-9]+)/([(0-9)]+[a-zA-Z]{0,1})/([(0-9)]+[a-zA-Z]{0,1})">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
            <a
              href="{concat('er:#HKWBV3_PT_',regex-group(1),'/',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3))}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </a>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>    
</xsl:template>
```

When i'm using the above XSLT, `<xsl:non-matching-substring>` block is getting called and when i tried the same REGEX in regexpal.com, the condition was accepting. please let me know where am i going wrong in my REGEXmatch.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a good reason to use `{0,1}` rather than the standard regex `?` "match zero or once"? (Although it should not cause your problem.)

Comment: Hi @Jongware, thanks for responding, do you want me to replace `{0,1}` with `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, `{0,1}` is the cause of the problem -- but not for the reason I thought!

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string:

> **Note:**
>
> Because the regex attribute is an attribute value template, curly brackets within the regular expression must be doubled. For example, to match a sequence of one to five characters, write `regex=".{{1,5}}"`. For regular expressions containing many curly brackets it may be more convenient to use a notation such as `regex="{'[0-9]{1,5}[a-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}'}"`, or to use a variable.

Since here you only use `{0,1}` you can use a single `?` instead, but of course that's not always an option.

Comment: Hi @Jongware based on your suggestion i tried the following REGEX `([A-Z][0-9]+)/([(0-9)]+\w+?)/([(0-9)]+[\w+]?)` on this string `U1/2/6`, and it is not working, please let me know where am i going wrong. Thanks

Comment: @user2423959: all I suggested was replacing `{0,1}` with `?`. Your regex works in TextPad, but perhaps XSLT2 does not like the backslashes in yours (these are new and were not present in the original). Nevertheless .. please try to stay on topic. Does this answer fix your *original* issue?

Comment: actually the string i mentioned in the comment is a new string pattern that needs to be matched, and the backslashes are for pattern matching.

Comment: @user2423959: My answer is based on *your original question* -- so **does doubling the braces work**? Please note that other people having the same question will find this discussion; as it is, it seems the problem is still *unresolved*.